# Super+L shows Unity-Greeter, not webkit2-greeter

Tags: unity, lightdm, webkit

I have installed webkit2-greeter for lightdm. When I boot, or run `dm-tool switch-to-greeter` I get the webkit2 greeter. However, when I use the keyboard combination Super+L, it sends me to the unity-greeter screen. Is there a configuration I need to change to switch what it uses as the lock greeter? Do I need to override the shortcut somehow?

Comment: yes, this is asked frequently. I personally haven't found a way, and best approach i have is to switch to bind super+L to dm-tool command. maybe someone else has better ideas

Comment: Sorry if this is a duplicate, I was unable to find any other questions in my searching.  I was considering a custom binding as a solution, but I was hoping there was a better one.